# Android - AWS s3 google sign-in

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, google-signin

i want to implement **google sign-in** with **Amazon Cognito**

AWS docs said "***Use Android API level 23 or higher***" but my app **minSdk=15**

can anyone mention another way to support api 15 ?

Comment: imho you could still use a web view and sign in as a web app

Answer (score 1):

The aws-android-sdk-auth-ui library requires a minimum version of API level 23. To support API 15, you can do the following: (the following are the steps that the AWS Auth SDK does)

Follow the tutorial on integrating Google SignIn into your app from the Google SignIn SDK for Android. Once you get the JWT token after the signin is successful, you can do the following to federate the token with Amazon Cognito.

```
final Map<String, String> loginMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
loginMap.put("accounts.google.com", "JWT-Token");
cognitoCredentialsProvider.clear();
cognitoCredentialsProvider.withLogins(loginMap);
cognitoCredentialsProvider.refresh();
```